# knockout.js templates with foreach object fails

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-2.0

This piece of binding with a template and a foreach fails:

```
<div data-bind="template: { name: 'tmplA', foreach: { data: items } }">
</div>

<script id="tmplA" type="text/html">
    <h1 data-bind="text: text"></h1>
</script>
```

The javascript code I use for the binding:

```
ko.applyBindings(
{
    items:
    [
        {
            text: "A"
        },
        {
            text: "B"
        }
    ]
});
```

Fiddle that shows the error:
http://jsfiddle.net/ab3RN/2/

The reason I use **foreach: { data: items }** is to be able to also use afterAdd, afterRender, etc. I want to be able to call a callback each time a new item is rendered.

If I just use **foreach: items** the binding works without problems.

Is it a bug or am I doing this wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
It works?
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ab3RN/3/

You cant wrap it with a object literal like you did.

Just a side note, using render and added callbacks is a antipattern because you get dependencies to DOM from ViewModel. Use custom bindings instead

edit: Example of custom binding
http://jsfiddle.net/2XTSt/

**update**
What Adrian wanted was a string template source
http://jsfiddle.net/2XTSt/1/

Comment: Good point with the antipattern. I will consider that and look into custom bindings. Thanx!

Comment: Could I please ask you to show me how to add a custom bindings handler that goes off every time an item is added?

Comment: Every item in the foreach adds new additional html to each item. This html is loaded off a server, so I cannot bind it at the same time as the parent html. 

For everyitem that is added to the list I want to bind to an ItemModel.

Comment: Well, identify what DOM actions you wanna do on each item, and move that to a custom binding?

Comment: In my case each item will be populated with more html. I would like to bind each newly populated item to it's own ItemModel. Would you consider that to be legit to do in the custom binding handler?

Comment: I do not understand the question, the template binding have already binded each item in array to the html in the template

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36301/discussion-between-adrian-rosca-and-anders)